# Chrome Extension JavaScript not inserting value into paragraph tag

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Hi there I'm learning how to create a v3 chrome extension and I'm having an issue inserting text into a paragraph I have tried inserting a document.getelementbyid that doesn't seem to work I have also tried using a document.body.innerHTML that did work but it displayed the value on the body of the page and not the chrome extension body

**Manifest.JSON**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Stader HBAR Staking",
    "version": "0.1",
    "action": {
        "16": "/images/HBARLogo.png",
        "48": "/images/HBARLogo.png",
        "128": "/images/HBARLogo.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "description": "This extention works with Stader Hedera staking to get the amount of reward you have recieved so far.",
    "icons": {
        "16": "/images/HBARLogo.png",
        "48": "/images/HBARLogo.png",
        "128": "/images/HBARLogo.png"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
          "matches": ["https://hedera.staderlabs.com/lt-pools"],
          "css": ["style.css"],
          "js": ["background.js"]
        }
      ]
}
```

**Javascript File**

```
    setTimeout(function (){
      let amount = document.querySelector(".bg-dark-600 > .flex > .flex-center > .LSPoolsEstimate_value__jdEKi").innerHTML;
      let currentAmount = document.querySelector(".MuiGrid-root > .flex-center > .LSPoolsForm_root__XqBrI > .LSPoolsForm_container__hcfZ2 > .LSPoolsFormLaToLx_root__DP9bV > form > .LSPoolsFormLaToLx_available_amount_validation__jOOGH > .flex:nth-child(2) > .Typography_root__nvhLo").innerHTML;
      removingFirstItem = currentAmount.split("~").pop();
      removingSecondItem = removingFirstItem.split("HBAR").shift();
      currentValue = removingSecondItem.trim();
      
      
      console.log(amount);
      let doCalculation = amount * currentValue;
      console.log(doCalculation);

      let youHaveEarned = doCalculation - amount;
      console.log(youHaveEarned);
      document.getElementById("initialAmount").innerHTML = totalAmountEarned

    }, 2000)();
```

**HTML File**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="bodyofex">
      <p id="initialAmount"></p>
    </div>

    <script src="./background.js">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The popup is a separate page, not related to the web page, so you can't load the same script both in the popup and as a content script. You need a separate script for the popup loaded in popup.html and another script as a content script for the web page. Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.

Comment: So how would I be able to do the script on the popup with having to do script on the web app using the content script, also would it be able to access the web app values from the popup script ?

Comment: You can use messaging or chrome.storage to pass the values.